# jQuery UI tooltip - dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-tooltip

I want to change the contents of the tooltip as I drag the div that has the tooltip. I would like to show the ui.position.top in the tooltip using the drag event for the div. Is this possible? I know the [jQuery UI API docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-content) regarding tooltip content says:

> When changing this option, you likely need to also change the items option.

but I cannot figure out how to do this correctly.

This is what I have:

**HTML**

```
<div id="box" title="original">drag me</div>
```

**JS**

```
$("#box").tooltip({
    track: true
});
$("#box").draggable({
    drag: function(event,ui){
        $(this).tooltip("option", "content", ui.position.top);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/E9vf3/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [detailed in the API](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-content) you can get or set the `content` option, after initialization. Your latest amend to your question is almost right but the `tooltip` is expecting a string as the final value.

```
$("#box").tooltip({
    track: true
});
$("#box").draggable({
    drag: function(event,ui){
        $(this).tooltip( "option", "content", ""+ui.position.top );
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/E9vf3/10/